# Firebase Authentication for Realm Cloud using JWT and a Google Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, realm, google-cloud-functions, realm-cloud

I am attempting to use JWTs to authenticate into Realm Cloud.  I am using Firebase as the authentication service and am attempting to create a Google Cloud Function to generate the JWT.  I generated the private and public keys using the terminal command "ssh-keygen".  Realm's JWT tutorial suggested the following line of code to read the key file:

```
const key = fs.readFileSync('./functions/id_rsa', 'utf8');
```

I copied the private key over to the project, pointed the code above to the file, but when I deploy the Google Cloud Function, I received the following error message:

> ⚠  functions[myAuthFunction(us-central1)]: Deployment error. Function
>   failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js
>   can't be loaded. Is there a syntax error in your code? Detailed stack
>   trace: Error: ENOENT: **no such file or directory, open
>   './functions/id_rsa'**

My project structure is as follows:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEsgV.png)

I have attempted to ask on Realm's forums but I haven't received much help.  The entire cloud function they suggested is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const key = fs.readFileSync(’pathToMyPrivateKeyFile');
exports.myAuthFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {    
    const uid = context.auth.uid 
    const payload = { userId: uid }    
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, { key: key, passphrase: "your-passphrase" }, { algorithm: 'RS256'}),    
    return { token:token }
});
```

In summary, how can the google cloud function read my private key file in my project?  The public key is stored inside my Realm Cloud dashboard for the specific instance.

Sources:
[Realm Cloud JWT Firebase tutorial](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/user-authentication/jwt-authentication/firebase-authentication-with-realm-cloud)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing just `./id_rsa` or `id_rsa`. I believe the path root is where the index.js file is.